# Find missing records with grouping

Tags: sql, hive, impala

I am struggling in implementing SQL query for identifying missing records from 2 HIVE tables based on grouping scenario. Data is as below

Table 1 - Calendar

```
month_last_day
20190131
20190229
20190331
20190430
```

Table 2 - Items

```
itemid date
101    20190131
101    20190229
101    20190331
102    20190131
102    20190331
102    20190430
```

Calendar in above tables is a master table containing all the dates and Items table contain data for different item id against which some dates from master table is missing. For e.g itemid 101 has date 20190430 missing and 102 is missing 20190229.

I need output which renders 2 rows as 101 20190430 and another row 102 20190229.

I have tried right outer join, exists concepts but nothing is working since filteration is needed against grouped records. Please suggest.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: Impala SQL on Hive tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cross join` calendar to distinct items and `left join` the items table to get the missing rows.

```
select i.itemid,c.month_last_day
from calendar c 
cross join (select distinct itemid from items) i
left join items it on it.itemid = i.itemid and c.month_last_day = it.dt
where it.dt is null
```

Comment: looks like join is not producing date record with value null. This is my main problem. not sure why

Comment: not sure what you are talking about. see a working example here https://rextester.com/LOACI93040

Comment: Somehow left join was not helping in my case but when i replaced it with "where not  exists" clause it worked. Thanks to you for suggesting cross join concept. It did help me. Thanks again,

Answer (score 0):

Query in hive, using cross join and left outer join.

```
with calendar as 
(select '20190131' last_day union all
 select '20190229' last_day union all
 select '20190331' last_day union all
 select '20190430' 
) 
,items as 
(select 101 itemid,'20190131' dt union all
 select 101 itemid,'20190229' dt union all
 select 101 itemid,'20190331' dt union all
 select 102 itemid,'20190131' dt union all
 select 102 itemid,'20190331' dt union all
 select 102 itemid,'20190430' dt
),
res1 as 
(select i.itemid, c.last_day from calendar c, (select distinct itemid from items) i)

select res1.itemid, res1.last_day from res1 left outer join items i on res1.itemid = i.itemid and res1.last_day=i.dt where i.dt is null;
```